# How to make an element stretch to the same height as its container?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, stretch

How to make a div overflow when it is larger than its container when height cannot be specified?

**Prerequisites:**

- `.Wrap` is variable in height and *cannot* have a set `height`.
- `.Head` should be a fixed height.
- `.Body` should become sccrollable when it is larger in height than its
  container (`.Wrap`)

The plan here is to make `.Body` stretch to fit `.Wrap` causing `overflow` to trigger.

**CURRENT CSS**

```
.Wrap{
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    display:flex wrap;
    align-items:stretch;
    max-height:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.Head{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
.Body{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6TaR/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try specifying a `min-height` for `.Head` (to prevent flexbox from forcibly collapsing it), and set the flex-flow property of the parent `.Wrap` element to `column nowrap`:

```
.Wrap{
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items:stretch;
    background:#ddd;
    max-height:50%;
    max-width:50%;
    padding:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.Head{
    background:#e00;
    height:50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6TaR/6/

Comment: Do you know how long I've been messing with this to make it work? Your a genius brother. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The body should have a definite height. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6TaR/4/).

```
.Body{
    background:#555;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: No definite height can be specified. Containers are variable. If I could set a height the problem would be easy.

Comment: you may have to use jquery to compute for the max-height of the .Body.

Comment: thanks for that. I was hoping to avoid that. I am positive this is possible using the new flexbox model.